# Running a simple.py on gem5 gives an error "NameError: name 'DDR3_1600_x64' is not defined"

Tags: python, gem5

I am new to gem5 and I am trying to run a simple.py script from "http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~markhill/cs757/Spring2016/learning_gem5/_downloads/simple.py".

I am getting an error as follows:
File "configs/tutorial1/simple2.py", line 46, in module system.mem_ctrl = DDR3_1600_x64() 
NameError: name 'DDR3_1600_x64' is not defined.

Can anyone please suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2):

I ran into a similar error; replace "x64" with "8x8". If you're having the same issues that I'm having, you may get another error with "LiveProcess" - replace "LiveProcess" with "Process".

Comment: Welcome to SO! This looks like a comment to the question instead of an answer. If you intend to comment, you need to have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) to [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) on any post. Also check this [what can I do instead](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).